# SQL query in access vba

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have problem with this UPDATE query , I have got message about syntax error query. I think that this query is correct and I can't find what is giving this error.

[Link to error](http://imageshack.us/a/img829/5702/29ta.png)

```
Private Sub cmdModifyBook_Click() 'approves modifying books to the database

Dim str As String
Dim dbs As DAO.Database

Set dbs = CurrentDb()

'checks if the typed all the data of book
If (Me.txtModifyTitle.Value = "") Or (Me.txtModifyTitleWeb.Value = "") Or (Me.txtModifyVerkaufpreis.Value = "") _
   Or (Me.txtModifyThemengruppe.Value = "") Then
   MsgBox "Nicht alle von Ihnen eingegebenen Daten"
   Exit Sub
End If

str = " UPDATE Katalog " _
    & "(Bezeichnung, BezeichnungWeb, Verkaufspreis, Themengruppe) SET " _
    & "('" & Me.txtModifyTitle.Value & "', '" & Me.txtModifyTitleWeb.Value & "', '" & Me.txtModifyVerkaufpreis.Value & "', '" & Me.txtModifyThemengruppe.Value & "') WHERE ID_Buch =" & Me.lblModifyID.Caption & ";"

dbs.Execute str, dbFailOnError

MsgBox "Das Buch wurde in der Datenbank geändert", vbInformation

dbs.Close
Set dbs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should look like this instead:

```vb
Private Sub cmdModifyBook_Click() 'approves modifying books to the database

    Dim str As String
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database

    Set dbs = CurrentDb()

    'checks if the typed all the data of book
    If (Me.txtModifyTitle.Value = "") Or (Me.txtModifyTitleWeb.Value = "") Or (Me.txtModifyVerkaufpreis.Value = "") _
       Or (Me.txtModifyThemengruppe.Value = "") Then
       MsgBox "Nicht alle von Ihnen eingegebenen Daten"
       Exit Sub
    End If

    str = "UPDATE Katalog " & _
    "SET Bezeichnung = '" & PQ(Me.txtModifyTitle.Value) & "', " & _
    "BezeichnungWeb = '" & PQ(Me.txtModifyTitleWeb.Value) & "', " & _
    "Verkaufspreis = '" & PQ(Me.txtModifyVerkaufpreis.Value) & "', " & _
    "Themengruppe = '" & PQ(Me.txtModifyThemengruppe.Value) & "' " & _
    "WHERE ID_Buch = " & Me.lblModifyID.Caption & ";"

    Debug.Print str
    MsgBox str

    dbs.Execute str, dbFailOnError

    MsgBox "Das Buch wurde in der Datenbank geändert", vbInformation

    dbs.Close
    Set dbs = Nothing

End Sub 

Private Function PQ(s as string) as String
    PQ = Replace(s, "'", "''")
End Function
```

Be aware that you need to replace any single quotes that might exist inside the values from the textboxes with two single quotes to prevent SQL errors. That's why I posted the PQ function.

Comment: After copy of this query still I have the same mistake :(

Comment: OK, I changed it a little. If it still doesn't work, can you do a `Debug.Print str` and post the result from your immediate window on your question above? What does your SQL actually look like with values in it?

Comment: Still I'm doing something wrong: [code + error](http://img829.imageshack.us/img829/3922/5z0f.png)

Comment: You will need to move the PQ Function outside of your current sub/function.

Comment: Is ID_Buch a numeric or text field? What about the other four fields? Are they all text?

Answer (score -1):

The UPDATE command syntax is as follows

```
UPDATE Katalog 
SET
Bezeichnung = Me.txtModifyTitle.Value ,
BezeichnungWeb = Me.txtModifyTitleWeb.Value ,
Verkaufspreis = Me.txtModifyVerkaufpreis.Value,
Themengruppe = Me.txtModifyThemengruppe.Value
WHERE ID_Buch = Me.lblModifyID.Caption
```

Of course the above will now work since you have to adopt it for str variable